# How do you stop windows 7 from auto streaming mp3's online?

Tags: windows-7, mp3, autoplay

Be it IE, Firefox or Chrome whenever I try to download a media file windows 7 starts streaming it in the browser instead of giving me options about what I want to do with the file i'm trying to download. I know the problem is with the OS and not the browser because I can download the file just fine off the website when I use Ubuntu. I get the feeling somewhere a setting is saying "open all mp3's in browser" but I dont know where to find or change it. Can anyone help?

Edit: If I click on the FLAC version of the audio file, windows 7 automatically downloads it.
If I click on the MP3 version, it automatically streams it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of browsers have a right-click menu item for downloading items. Instead of clicking the item, right-click on it and chose the download/"save target as..." option.